# Draggable does not work in extjs6.5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

I am using the below code -

```
afterListeners: function(thisEl, eOpts) {
    sliderSprite = Ext.create('Ext.draw.sprite.Rect', {
            width: spriteWidth, // half year width height : 20, x : 16, y : 0, draggable : true, floatable : true, 'stroke-width' : 2, fill : '#FCE5C5', stroke : '#C6B395' });

            sliderSprite.show(true);
            thisEl.getSurface().add(sliderSprite);
            alert("before source");

            new Ext.drag.Source({
                element: sliderSprite,
                constrain: {
                    // Drag only horizontal in 30px increments
                    horizontal: true, //                                                snap: { //                                                  y: 30 //                                                }
                },
                onDragMove: function() {
                    alert("inside source");
                    spriteHighlighter.remove();
                    me.onDragSprite(e, this, chartWidth, spriteWidth);
                },
                onDragEnd: function() {
                    me.refreshCharts(xPlots, bigChart, sliderSprite, firstYear, lastYear, chartWidth);
                }

            });
            alert("outside source");

        },
    }
}
```

Now, the issue is, control doesn't go inside the `Ext.drag.Source()`. I get 2 alert messages ,before source and outside source. and because it doesn't go inside `Ext.drag.Source()`.

The drag-able functionality of the element is not working. What should I do ?

Comment: Your code is not clear provide more source code.

Comment: my question is - how to use  Ext.drag.Source () ?

Comment: but you told drag-able not working. So my question is what you have tried can you  provide more info?

Comment: The reason drag-able is not working is because the way i am using Ext.drag.Source () is not right. That is the reason control is not going to the 'inside source' alert.

Comment: If you could please help me understand how should I use Ext.drag.Source () ?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905395/draggable-does-not-work-in-extjs6-5/50907629#50907629)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to be clear on which component you want to use. After that you need to put [`afterrender`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#event-afterrender) event on that component and inside of that event you can use [`Ext.drag.Source`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.drag.Source.html).

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2i6n)**, I have created a demo using `button` and `Ext.drag.Source`.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var buttons = [],
            rendomColor = () => {
                return "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
            };

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            buttons.push({
                text: `Button ${i+1}`,
                margin: 10,
                style: `background:${rendomColor()}`
            });
        }

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            height: window.innerHeight,
            title: 'Ext.drag.Source Example',
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'button'
            },
            items: buttons,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            listeners: {
                afterrender: function (panel) {
                    panel.items.items.forEach(item => {
                        new Ext.drag.Source({
                            element: item.el,
                            constrain: {
                                // Drag only vertically in 30px increments
                                //vertical: true,
                                snap: {
                                    y: 1,
                                    x: 1
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    })

                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Narendra. I'm a volunteer editor here, and one of the things I do is to try to maintain quality levels in question posts and answer posts. Every day I search for chatty phrases that do not add any utility to posts and remove them - it is part of why the quality levels on Stack Overflow are higher than other places.

Comment: With this in mind, may I ask you to refrain from adding "hope this helps" or "hope this will guide you to achieving your requirement". It is a nice platitude, but it does not add anything useful to the post, and editors prefer to remove it based on our general desire for brevity. We already have 160 of these to remove from your material, so it would save editors a good deal of time and effort if you would not add it again. Thank you.